# Can't load Json file in flutter application anymore

Tags: json, flutter

I created an language learning app, where the user can choose from various topics inside a language (f.e shopping, smalltalk, alphabet, consonants and so on). When the user taps a topic it will load a json file. The app worked totally fine and is already on the app store (it's called Sankofa). Now I wanted to add a new language and noticed that my Futurebuilder doesn't work anymore, thus the app won't load the json file.

The error I got is:

The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#a072a):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Here's the code that loads the json file:

```
class Json extends StatelessWidget {
  // accepting language as a parameter

  String topicname;
  late String assettoload;

  Json(this.topicname);

  setasset() {
    if (topicname == "farben") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/farben.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Fragewörter") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/fragewoerter.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Begrüßungen") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/saetze.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Konsonanten") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/konsonanten.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Selbstlaute") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/selbstlaute.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Wochentage") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/wochentage.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Zeitangaben") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/zeitangaben.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Einkaufen") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/einkaufen.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Konversation") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/konversation.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Richtungen") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/richtungsangaben.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Über mich") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/uebermich.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Wegweisung") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/wegweisungen.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Lebensmittel") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/lebensmittel.json";
    } else if (topicname == "Tiere") {
      assettoload = "assets/lerndateien/tiere.json";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // function called before the build
    // string assettoload is avialable to the DefaultAssetBuilder
    setasset();
    // return to the FutureBuilder to load and decode JSON
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (mydata == null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Row(
              children: [
                BackButton(),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Lädt...",
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried a lot of things (f.e if mydata == true) but nothing worked. I bet it's just a small fix and I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false), from this check you getting or load data from assets correctly or not. Because as the  error logs your getting null value instead of list

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're trying to access the snapshots `data` when it hasn't finished loading yet (no matter if it will be null or not) by using `toString()`.

Inside your Builder you need to handle the case while it is loading, **before** you can check if it loaded `null`.

```
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // This will execute when it is finished loading AND is not null
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          if (mydata == null) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Row(
                children: [
                  BackButton(),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                        "Lädt...",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
          }
        }
        /* other handling, example */

        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
     ...
```

Now, as you'll see in your IDE, the snapshot can have multiple `ConnectionState`s. See [here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-futurebuilder-widget-examples) for a decent example of how to handle other states.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your insightful comment. I implemented the code. Now the CircularProgessIndicator is being shown and the json file doesn't seem to load (its been loading for a minute now.) Why is the json file not loading?

Comment: And thank you for the website link. I will definitely read it.

Comment: When it worked, the json file popped in immediately without any loading time.